# create the cshtml file based on user defined controls (like automatic code generator)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, t4

We have input like the control type and the name (for eg : Control Type : Label, dropdowm, radio button , etc., and Control Name : lblID) On click of a Generate, I need a CShtml page which should be binded with all the controls. Is it possible to integrate T4 template with my solution. We are yet to start a new application.

Heard about T4 template but all the examples specified with scaffolding options. I don't have this. By generally i need to create cshtml under views of my project. Requesting suggestion. 
suggest a way to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share details on what you've already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Virus : we have input like the control type and the name (for eg : Control Type : Label, dropdowm, radio button , etc., and  Control Name : lblID)
On click of a Generate, I need a CShtml page which should be binded with all the controls.
Is it possible to integrate T4 template with my solution.
We are yet to start a new application.
Kindly suggest a way to proceed.

Comment: please update the original question with these details